# How to fit index report into ArcMap layout?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, grids-graticules, reports, map-index

I want to fit report into map. I'm creating grid and in order to index it I'm creating report. View > Create Report. It gives me a new window that includes texts. I want to fit texts for index points and ways. How can I fit index into my map ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have already created the report that you want to place on your layout.

The ArcGIS 10.2 Online Help has a page entitled [Creating a report](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004v00000002000000) which says:

> 19. From the **Report Viewer**, you can click the **Add Report To Layout** button to place the report on the map
>       layout